# Change value of protected property in PHP 7 from outside class

Tags: php, protected, solid-principles

What strategies are out there in PHP 7 for modifying a protected property of one class, Class B, from a method in a second class, Class A, even though these classes are not related?

In languages that implement nested classes, this would not be a problem at all. Class B could (and should) be nested in Class A. Then, Class B could be a protected class and the property could be public.

**Idea #1**

This is extremely easy if Class B is a child of Class A. But, these two classes are not related. Therefore, this is not even an option.

**Idea #2**

I thought about using a public method in Class B to change the value of the property, which could be called by Class A. Unfortunately, this allows **anyone** to change the value of the property, not just Class A.

**Idea #3**

My next idea was to get a pointer to the protected variable, set it from within Class A, then unset it. Something like this:

```
<?php

class A {

    protected $b;

    public function __construct() {

        $this->b = new B( $pointer );

        // do processing that requires B to be instantiated but has
        // not yet determined an appropriate value for the property

        $pointer = 12;
        unset( $pointer );

    }

}

class B {

    protected $value;

    public function __construct( &$pointer ) {

        $this->value =& $pointer;

    }

}

var_dump( new A );

?>
```

Would this make Class A and Class B tightly coupled? From my understanding, it would, and I would like to avoid that. I am hoping my *understanding* is wrong, and this is an acceptable solution.

Are there any other workarounds in PHP 7 that can accomplish this goal without breaking SOLID design principles?

Thank you all in advance for your time!

---

Since it's been requested, here's the actual problem I'm trying to solve. I have a class called Client and a class called Receipt. A Client object can be requested to send a message to server and it will return a Receipt object. This happens asynchronously, so later on in the script I can use the Receipt object to get the response (using a getResponse() method). I also want the receipt to have a getTime() method so that you can check to see how long the request/response cycle took to complete. This is a watered down version of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
<?php

class Client {

    protected $receipts = [];

    public function sendRequest( $destination, $request ) {

        // put response in database and get the inserted row ID

        $this->receipts[] = [

            'timeStart' => microtime( true ),
            'receipt' => ($receipt = new Receipt( $rowID ))

        ];

        return $receipt;

    }

    public function setSignal( $signal ) {

        pcntl_signal( $signal, function() {

            // while there is a new response in the database

                // get the $receipt from $this->receipts that matches the response

                $receipt->receipt->time = microtime( true ) - $receipt->timeStart;

                unset( $this->receipts[$index] );
                break;

            // end while

        } );

    }

}

class Receipt {

    protected $rowID, $time;

    public function __construct( $rowId ) {

        $this->rowID = $rowID;

    }

    public function getTime() {

        return $this->time;

    }

}

$client = new Client;
$client->setSignal( SIGIO );

$receipt = $client->sendRequest( 'some destination', 'my request' );

echo $receipt->getTime(); // NULL
sleep( 1 );
echo $receipt->getTime(); // NULL
sleep( 1 );
echo $receipt->getTime(); // NULL
sleep( 1 );
echo $receipt->getTime(); // NULL
sleep( 1 );
echo $receipt->getTime(); // 4.2

?>
```

So the problem line in there is:

$receipt->receipt->time = microtime( true ) - $receipt->timeStart;

Because "time" is a protected property of the Receipt object.

Comment: To clarify, this problem *should* be solved with nested classes. I'm assuming that Class B *belongs* to Class A. B is instantiated by A, it can be modified by A, and destroyed by A. But *only* by A. In PHP, I understand that there are many limitations, since there are no nested classes. I would like to implement it the best way I can, and this is one of those things I just don't see how to answer appropriately.

Comment: This may be more a case of having to check your OO design.  Knowing how two arbitrary classes are related and how they should interact is such a broad subject that it's difficult (IMHO) to recommend a way of doing this properly without resorting to language hacks.

Comment: Maybe it will be easier for us to give you proper advice/solution if we know what problem you're actually trying to solve. Right now, it kind of sounds like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Alright, thanks for the tip! I have edited the question to provide details about my specific problem.

Comment: In a nutshell: there's nothing that would enable such cross-class relationships in PHP, so you simply can't. You need to accept that your property is `public` and document how it's supposed to be used, or you need to resort to reflection if that's unacceptable.

Comment: Oh. Well that's sad :( Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so, I think I've come up with the best solution that I can given the original question (updating a protected variable from another class). I'm not sure how this stacks up with the SOLID principles, but I think it would be fairly well.

It seems to me that the best solution would be to create a public method that would allow the object to refresh *itself* from the row in the database, rather than a public method to specifically update the value after fetching it. Something like this:

```
<?php

class A {

    protected $database, $b;

    public function __construct() {

        $this->b = new B;

        // do HALF of the processing that requires B to be instantiated
        // but has not yet determined an appropriate value for the property

        $this->b->refresh();

    }

}

class B {

    protected $database, $value;

    public function refresh() {

        // do the other half of the things

        $this->value = 12;

    }

}

var_dump( new A );

?>
```

A comment on my original post pointed out that I was asking an XY Question. After reading the article, it made complete sense, and I understand that my question may have been tough to answer because of how I asked it. Thanks to everyone who tried, anyway! I will leave this here for anyone who encounters a similar problem.